AMP Mustache Template {{name}} Not Rendering Data from JSON Response
I'm working on an AMP page where I'm using amp-list with a Mustache template to display data from a JSON response. The JSON response from the server is correct and includes the name field, but the {{name}} placeholder in the Mustache template doesn't render any data.
JSON response
{
"items": [
    {"name": "London, England"},
    {"name": "London"},
    {"name": "City of London, England"},
    {"name": "Londonderry, Northern Ireland"}
]

}
AMP HTML code:
<amp-list width="auto" height="100" layout="fixed-height" 
      src="https://example.com/index.php?route=information/places/search" 
      [src]="'https://example.com/index.php?route=information/places/search&q=' + query">
<template type="amp-mustache">
    <div class="autocomplete-suggestion" role="button" tabindex="0">
        Name: {{name}}
    </div>
</template>
<div placeholder>Loading...</div>
<div fallback>No results found.</div>

The page validates as AMP, and the network tab shows the correct JSON response. The input shows a responsive dropdown depending on values entered, but the {{name}} field in the template doesn’t display any data. Could this be a server-side issue with getting the data on the controller and passing it to the view, or is there something I'm missing in the AMP setup?
Any insights would be appreciated!

Cause:
The issue was caused by the Twig templating engine in my framework, which uses the same {{ ... }} syntax for variable interpolation as AMP's Mustache. Twig was processing the {{name}} variables before they reached the Mustache template, causing them not to render.
Solution:
To prevent Twig from interpreting the Mustache syntax, I wrapped the Mustache template in a {% verbatim %} block. This tells Twig to ignore everything inside the block and treat it as plain text, allowing Mustache to process the variables correctly.
Really hope this helps someone else!
